# Error while running a dev prompt with vite (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, console, package.json, vite

just for some backstory, I created a few web front projects in Linux environment and I'm currently importing them. So I set up everything on my windows pc (npm, vite, node ...) but if I try to start developing while using a dev build, I got an error whether it's a previous project or a new one.

what I got from my prompt:
[image]

The French sentence says : "The specified path was not found"
The path after "Error: cannot find module (path)" doesn't even exist.

[image]

Do you guys have an idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

I tried updating everything, installing globally but nothing changed ...

Comment: vite.js is normally found in `node_modules\vite\bin`.  not sure why your project is not looking for it there.  try reinstalling dependencies by deleting both `package-lock` file and node_modules folder then `npm install`

Comment: I got the exact same error after trying this, no luck